# How to define a map in TOML?

Tags: go, toml

How to define a map in TOML?

For example, I want to define something like:

```
[FOO]

Usernames_Passwords='{"user1":"pass1","user2":"pass2"}'
```

and then in go convert them to a map[string]string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can have maps like this:

```
name = { first = "Tom", last = "Preston-Werner" }
point = { x = 1, y = 2 }
```

See: https://github.com/toml-lang/toml#user-content-inline-table

In your case, it looks like you want a password table, or an array of maps. You can make it like this:

```
[[user_entry]]
name = "user1"
pass = "pass1"

[[user_entry]]
name = "user2"
pass = "pass2"
```

Or more concisely:

```
user_entry = [{ name = "user1", pass = "pass1" },
              { name = "user2", pass = "pass2" }]
```

Comment: Updated document link: https://toml.io/en/v1.0.0#array-of-tables

Answer (score 6):

This works using [github.com/BurntSushi/toml](https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml) (does not support [inline tables](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml#user-content-inline-table)):

```
d := `
    [FOO.Usernames_Passwords]
    a="foo"
    b="bar"
    `
var s struct {
    FOO struct {
        Usernames_Passwords map[string]string
    }
}
_, err := toml.Decode(d, &s)
// check err!
fmt.Printf("%+v", s)
```

Using [github.com/naoina/toml](https://github.com/naoina/toml) this works (using inline tables):

```
d := `
    [FOO]
    Usernames_Passwords = { a = "foo" , b = "bar" }
    `
var s struct {
    FOO struct {
        Usernames_Passwords map[string]string
    }
}
err := toml.Unmarshal([]byte(d), &s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v", s)
```